# consecutive runs of shuffle function yielding same order

Tags: python, random, shuffle

I'm generating random lists but for some reason all three of the lists here end up with the same order. Two questions:

First, what's wrong with this code such that the three lists have the same order (i.e. target1 = target2 = target3 and jitter1 = jitter2 = jitter3)?

Second, and more importantly, is this the best way to generate these random lists? The purpose is to be able to run this script every time a new subject comes in so that each subject has three random lists associated with him/her. Is the shuffle function good to use for this purpose (i.e. random within the script and also differently random if I run the script a few hundred different times on different days)?

Thanks a bunch for any help.

```
import random
import sys
import csv

N = 200 # number of targets
l = 3 # number of lists to generate
l += 1

# generate lists
targets_M = ['stimuli/Hangul_M'+str(x)+'.png' for x in range(N/2)]
targets_F = ['stimuli/Hangul_F'+str(x)+'.png' for x in range(N/2)]

targets_null = targets_M + targets_F

delays = list(range(3, 13, 1)) # 3 : 12, n = 10

jitter_null = delays * 20

# randomize lists
for j in range(1,l):
    globals()["targets"+str(j)] = targets_null
    random.shuffle(globals()["targets"+str(j)])
    globals()["jitter"+str(j)] = jitter_null
    random.shuffle(globals()["jitter"+str(j)])
```

Comment: have you tried initialize the random generator with `random.seed([x])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you keep assigning the same list to the new variables that you generate so `random.shuffle` just shuffles the original list over and over. You should make a copy first.

```
# randomize lists
for j in range(1,l):
    t = targets_null[:]
    random.shuffle(t)
    globals()["targets"+str(j)] = t
    jj = jitter_null[:]
    random.shuffle(jj)
    globals()["targets"+str(j)] = jj
```

Using globals like this is awkward. You could just use lists. Assuming you want to associate jitter with target you can put them together in a tuple.

```
# randomize lists
targets = []
for _ in range(1,l):
    t = targets_null[:]
    random.shuffle(t)
    j = jitter_null[:]
    random.shuffle(j)
    targets.append((t,j))
```

Comment: the tuple suggestion is much appreciated. I love how much I learn about different approaches through this forum. thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

ah, I'm obviously new to python. I needed to use the code

```
globals()["targets"+str(j)] = targets_null[:]
```

to copy the variable and not just follow the pointer to the original variable that targets1 targets2 and targets3 were all pointing to. Lesson learned. Anyway, still curious about the best randomization scheme. Thanks!